# Open two popups with javascript. Not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I need to open two popups with a single button. I have this code

```
<script language="javascript">
function abrir2popup() {
a= window.open("http://example.com","", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=300, height=90, top=200, left=240");
b= window.open("http://example.com","", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=300, height=100, top=85, left=240");
setTimeout(function () { a.close();}, 10000);
setTimeout(function () { b.close();}, 10000);
}
</script>
<button value="send" onclick="abrir2popup();this.disabled=true;" />test</button>
```

In Chome, FF and Safari works fine. But in IE and Opera does not work. It can be solved? Opera does not matter much. IE is what worries me

Comment: You're basically opening a and closing b at the same time why two separate functions?

Comment: I am pretty new to javascript. It works, but if you can simplify the code, better!

Comment: Please define "`not working`". In IE this code opens only one pop-up, or not pop-ups at all, opens one or two tabs instead, or something else you didn't expect?